# How to kill a process with a single command?

Tags: command-line, process, kill

I want to kill a process, after finding the id in a single step.

I currently use these two commands:

```
pidof <name>
kill <#number_which_is_result_of_command>
```

How can I write a single command to do this?

Comment: What shell? `bash`? `tcsh`? ...?

Comment: You can look for *command substitution* in your shell's documentation.

Comment: I kill things visually by using: xkill . Just type xkill in the Terminal, move the cursor onto the offending app and press the button.Gone

Comment: @arochester That works, but is restricted to GUI environments, the `kill` variety of commands will work from the console (plus could be automated in scripts etc). Still good to make people aware of the `xkill` option for sure.

Comment: If one of the answers below solved your problem, please consider [accepting it by clicking the checkmark](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) next to the answer. It'll reward both parties with some rep points and mark this problem as solved.

Answer (score 20):

You can also kill processes by name:

Example:

```sh
pkill vim  # kill all processes containing vim in the process name
```

Comment: @Levon Are you sure? Hint: Will it work if you change `pkill` to `kill`?

Comment: It will not work,Levon. kill -9 kills the process by its PID and pkill -9 kills process by its name.

Comment: Without `-o` or `-n`, `pkill` also kills *all* matching processes, not just one.

Comment: -1 for suggesting to use SIGKILL (-9), which is bad process ecology.  With SIGKILL, data within the process is not flushed, creating possible data corruption.

Comment: @Arcege You could edit for that, it's a side point.

Comment: Suggesting `killall` is VERY BAD ADVICE. It does very different things depending on which Unix/Linux you're on.

Answer (score 14):

To answer your specific question with your set of commands, use:

```
kill `pidof <name>`
```

Since `pidof <name>` gives you the PID of the process you are trying to kill you can use it with command line switches such as `-9` etc too.

Tested with `bash` and `tcsh`.

Comment: BTW, `kill $(pidof <name>)` is more compatible (POSIX) and can be used inside of another _command substitution_ block.

Comment: @RudolfAdamkovic I agree, that is a better option, for sure in scripts. However for a quick typed command I find using the backticks easier .. plus it works with both common shells (bash and tcsh) .. I couldn't get the `$` version to work with tcsh.

Comment: Just tried it with `tcsh` and you're right. Didn't know that. Thanks for info!

Answer (score 8):

Should be a comment on Levon's, but I lack the rep here to do so:

Riffing on the discussion in the accepted answer of this question: https://serverfault.com/questions/397762/how-to-make-folders-00-99-with-a-single-command-in-ubuntu

I'd say it could be preferable (or at least useful/clearer for later searchers) to run

```
kill $(pidof <name>)
```

Further reference on $() vs. ``: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Comment: +1 for including the bottom link especially. I received a similar comment from @RudolfAdamkovic, see my reply to him. Do you know a version of this that works with tcsh? (I still find backticks easier to type on a quick command in the shell :)

Comment: I've only worked with bash (on Linux) & ksh (on HP-UX); haven't crossed paths with tcsh yet, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `killall` command to kill the particular process.

```
killall vim
```